# how to convert datetime to date in DataView.RowFilter in c#?

Tags: c#, asp.net, datetime, tableview

I have to get only the rows that has end date today. But in my case my end date is a `DateTime` Column.

I tried the below code

```
DataView dvFormula = dsFormula.Tables[0].DefaultView;
dvFormula.RowFilter = "date(EndDateTime)='" + startDate.ToString("yyyyMMdd") + "'";
dvFormula.Sort = "FromDateTime ASC";
```

But `date(EndDateTime)` is not working.

Comment: Why not do this filtering on SQL side itself!

Comment: @niksofteng It is a machine output, So I am not able to do that in my case

Comment: what type is the time stamp in your datatable? is it a .net DateTime? is it a string? if so, in what format is the string?

Comment: @DrNachtschatten it is a datetime in format **6/1/2017 1:30:11 PM**

Comment: @jafarbtech you could build a loop comparing the `DateTime.Now.Date` to each rows end datetime.Date, if match, add to new collection.

Comment: @DrNachtschatten it ll work, but it wont be a good practice, right?

Answer (score 0):

try comparing with LIKE, it compares if a part of the EndDateTime equals your startDate.

```
dvFormula.RowFilter = "EndDateTime LIKE '*" + startDate.ToString("yyyyMMdd") + "*'";
```